# Stop TinyMCE 4.1.9 from removing orphaned children tags

Tags: tinymce-4

I am wanting to use **ANY** tag inside of TinyMCE without it being removed, but it's not working.  My current input is:

```
<tr><td>[item-thumb]</td><td>[item-count]</td><td>[item-location]</td><td>[item-title]</td><td>[item-desc]</td><td>[low-estimate]</td></tr>
```

This is used to iterate through items and replace the short-codes with item data, and put that into a table.  However, it always strips out the `tr` and `td` tags because it is not wrapped in a `table` tag.

I've tried:

```
valid_elements: "+*[*]",
valid_children: "+*[*]",
extended_valid_elements: "+*[*]",
verify_html: false,
cleanup: false,
cleanup_on_startup : false,
```

I know some of these are deprecated, but I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that TinyMCE is designed to create valid, well-formed (X)HTML.  If you attempt to create table related tags but don't wrap them in a table the HTML cleanup/validation routine will always do its best to cleanup the content to make it valid.

There is no way to disable this validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you just wrap them in a `<table>`, then just remove `<table>` and `</table>` just before saving?**

I have done that for something else, but with TinyMCE.

**I have the full code in the textarea** (where the content of the TinyMCE is), and then **used javascript to remove the unwanted code** (`<table>` and `</table>` in your case) **before saving it** to a file.

It will work this way:
IF you load the content of the textarea from a database, then just prefix and suffix the content with what you need to make TinyMCE work.

Then get the content from the textarea when you are going to save it, BUT remove the prefix and suffix before writing it to the database/ file.

Doing this should be easy, and gives you endless possibilities.

(You could either do that by javascript, or by PHP (or whatever server side language you use).)

Comment: Well this is what I did originally.  But then the issue was that not everyone will be using tables.  I only need this fix for those that are.

Comment: Isn't that easy to do by make the code look for ´<tr>´ (table rows), and then insert ´<table>´ before the first ´<tr>´and then ´</table>´ after the last ´</tr>´?

Comment: However I don't understand why you'd allow ´<tr>´ but not ´<table>´ to be saved?

Comment: This is because the user is creating an item template which will be repeated for each item.  If they want them all in a table, they would need to wrap the shortcode which produces the item template in a table tag, then the item template would need to be the table rows.